# How to ensure systemd does not start a unit until udev has created the device node

Tags: mount, systemd, udev

I want to mount a UBI filesystem during boot. Depending on the configuration, the MTD device number could vary from build to build, but it will always be the partition called `add`.

I have added the following files

```
# /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/76-mtd-alias.rules
ACTION!="add", GOTO="mtd_alias_end"
SUBSYSTEM=="mtd", SYMLINK="mtd-byname/$attr{name}", TAG+="systemd"
LABEL="mtd_alias_end"
```

this creates files like `/dev/mtd-by-name/add` as a symlink to the relevant `/dev/mtdblockX` file (where `X` is configuration dependent).

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/mnt-data.mount
[Unit]
Description=Mount data partition
Requires=data-attach.service
After=data-attach.service
[Mount]
What=ubi0_0
Where=/mnt/data
Type=ubifs
```

together with

```
#/usr/lib/systemd/system/data-attach.service
[Unit]
Description=Attach data ubi partition

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
Requires=dev-mtd\x2dbyname-add.device
After=dev-mtd\x2dbyname-add.device
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ubiattach /dev/ubi_ctrl -p /dev/mtd-byname/add
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/ubidetach /dev/ubi_ctrl -p /dev/mtd-byname/add
```

The problem is that although `systemd` *does* start the `data-attach.service`, it still does it before `udev` has created the symlinks.

After the system has booted, I can see that the `device` was started, though the mount failed:

```
# systemctl status data-attach.service
● data-attach.service - Attach data ubi partition
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/data-attach.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-06-22 11:11:50 UTC; 7min ago
  Process: 164 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ubiattach /dev/ubi_ctrl -p /dev/mtd-byname/add (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 164 (code=exited, status=255)

Jun 22 11:11:50 LogiPeru ubiattach[164]: libubi: error!: cannot stat "/dev/mtd-byname/add"
Jun 22 11:11:50 LogiPeru ubiattach[164]:         error 2 (No such file or directory)
Jun 22 11:11:50 LogiPeru ubiattach[164]: ubiattach: error!: cannot attach "/dev/mtd-byname/add"
Jun 22 11:11:50 LogiPeru ubiattach[164]:            error 2 (No such file or directory)
Jun 22 11:11:50 LogiPeru systemd[1]: Starting Attach data ubi partition...
Jun 22 11:11:50 LogiPeru systemd[1]: data-attach.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jun 22 11:11:50 LogiPeru systemd[1]: data-attach.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 22 11:11:50 LogiPeru systemd[1]: Failed to start Attach data ubi partition.
```

But the `device` did load:

```
# systemctl status 'dev-mtd\x2dbyname-add.device'
● dev-mtd\x2dbyname-add.device - /dev/mtd-byname/add
   Follow: unit currently follows state of sys-devices-virtual-mtd-mtd10.device
   Loaded: loaded
   Active: active (plugged) since Fri 2018-06-22 11:11:50 UTC; 10min ago
   Device: /sys/devices/virtual/mtd/mtd10
# ls -l /dev/mtd-byname/add
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jun 22 11:11 /dev/mtd-byname/add -> ../mtd10
```

Where did I go wrong? Why are the `Requires` and `After` labels in the `data-attach.service` getting ignored? If I wait till I can login, then I can run `systemctl start mnt-data.mount` and the mount succeeds.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> [Service]
> <...>
> Requires=dev-mtd\x2dbyname-add.device
> After=dev-mtd\x2dbyname-add.device
> ```

You have to put the [`Requires=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=) and [`After=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit=) directives into the `[Unit]` section of the unit file. They will not work in either the `[Service]` or any other section.

An advice for future diagnosis: `systemctl daemon-reload`, like other `systemctl` verbs, writes its warnings and errors only into the system log and not into the `systemctl`'s stdout/stderr (i. e. the console). `systemctl daemon-reload`, in particular, only reports failure on critical errors, like failure to talk to `systemd`. Hence it may be beneficial to manually check the system log with something like `journalctl -e _PID=1` after any `systemctl` commands.

Comment: @NickStoughton please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.